# How can I duplicate the content of my tabs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

How can I duplicate the content of my tabs?

Hi, I'm new to ionic. I have two tabs called "dashboard" and "friends". I basically want the content of both tabs to be the same and share the same view and controller.
if I click on the content of "dahsaboard" it must be the same content of "friends" and vice versa. what I am trying to do is that when the user clicks on any of the tabs you can get the name of the tab, if for example I click on "dashboard" you must return the word "dashboard", the same with the tab " friends ", how can I do it ?.

thank you very much

```
.state('tab.dash', {
  url: '/dash',
  views: {
    'tab-dash': {
      templateUrl: 'tab-dash.html',
      controller: 'DashCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('tab.friends', {
  url: '/friends',
  views: {
    'tab-friends': {
      templateUrl: 'tab-dash.html',
      controller: 'DashCtrl'
    }
  }
})


<ion-tab title="Dashboard" icon="icon ion-home" href="#/tab/dash">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>


<ion-tab title="Friends" icon="icon ion-heart" href="#/tab/friends">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-friends"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **`on-select`** event for ion-tabs change event

```
<ion-tab on-select="doSomeForcontent('Friends')"  title="Friends" icon="icon ion-heart" href="#/tab/friends">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-friends"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

and in controller,

```
$scope.doSomeForcontent = function(value){
  check here for tab name and do the logic
}
```

Comment: you need to paste that in the main controller

Comment: this is my code.. It not works for me :( can you help me please ? http://plnkr.co/edit/XmPNTx27gOvnpalrvVMj?p=preview